# How to write unit test for React Native Switch's value prop

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I am using React Native Switch. I want to write a unit test (using jest and testing-library/react-native) for its `value` prop. But there is no `value` in its `props`

My use case is there will be a default value for the `Switch` when the page load. But I can not find a way to check the Switch value. Is there a correct way to check if its `value` is true or false?[image]

Picture attached is the Switch's list of props

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of the prop like this, including if it works when you change it:

```
expect(screen.getByRole('switch').props.value).toBe(true);

fireEvent(screen.getByRole('switch'), 'onValueChange');

expect(screen.getByRole('switch').props.value).toBe(false);
```

Assuming your component looks something like this:

```
    <Switch
      trackColor={{true: something, false:somethingElse}}
      thumbColor={someColor}
      ios_backgroundColor={somethingSomething}
      onValueChange={toggleValue}
      value={value}
    />
```

with somthing like `const [value, toggleValue] = useState(false);` for the value.
Let me know if this doesn't work for you, please also add the component and the test you have now. It is hard to say what's going wrong without seeing that